# Subsequent PFObject.saveAll() doesn't work in iOS Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This method is called twice in a row, once for Emails, and again for Phone numbers, in an attempt to save that info to a separate object for each contact as I couldn't figure out how to save nested arrays to a single Parse object.

The baffling thing is that if I only do the method for emails, all save fine.  If I only do it for Phone numbers, all save fine.  When I do emails and then phones, only phones save.  When I do phones and then emails, emails save.

The exception is that if a given contact only has an email or phone it always succeeds.  Commenting out the pointer to Contacts didn't do anything to help, so it appears there's some race condition or locking error that's going on here with Parse.

Any ideas?  I'd love to learn how to do nested arrays to parse too if that's possible, but I tried a few things and couldn't figure out how to get that to work.

```
func updateMultiField(person: ABRecord, parseObject: PFObject, fieldToGrab: ABPropertyID, contact: PFObject){
    var multiArray:ABMultiValueRef = extractABMultiRef(ABRecordCopyValue(person, fieldToGrab))!
    var parseObjects: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
    for (var j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiArray); ++j){
        var multi =  MultiRef()
        var multiValueRaw = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiArray, j)
        multi.value = extractMultiValue(multiValueRaw)

        if (multi.value != nil) {
            //get type
            multi.type = getMultiType(fieldToGrab)
            //get label
            multi.label = extractMultiLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiArray, j))
            //get id
            multi.id = String(Int(ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex(multiArray, j)))

            parseObject[parseContactIdFieldName] = contact
            parseObject[labelFieldName] = multi.label
            parseObject[valueFieldName] = multi.value
            parseObject[multiIdFieldName] = multi.id
            parseObject[typeFieldName] = multi.type
            println("\(multi.type) multi about to be saved with value of \(multi.value)")
            parseObjects.insert(parseObject, atIndex: j)
            //save
        }//if
    }//for
    PFObject.saveAll(parseObjects)
}//updateField
```

An earlier method calls this method twice:

```
updateMultiField(person, parseObject: multis, fieldToGrab: kABPersonPhoneProperty, contact: contact)
updateMultiField(person, parseObject: multis, fieldToGrab: kABPersonEmailProperty, contact: contact)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE:

Here's the fixed code, which no longer passes a PFObject into the method and tries to save the same object over and over, but rather instantiates it in the for loop (5th line), which resolves the problem:

```
func updateMultiField(person: ABRecord, fieldToGrab: ABPropertyID, contact: PFObject){
    var multiArray:ABMultiValueRef = extractABMultiRef(ABRecordCopyValue(person, fieldToGrab))!
    var parseObjects: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
    for (var j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiArray); ++j){
        var parseObject = PFObject(className: multisObjectName)
        var multi =  MultiRef()
        var multiValueRaw = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiArray, j)
        multi.value = extractMultiValue(multiValueRaw)

        if (multi.value != nil) {
            //get type
            multi.type = getMultiType(fieldToGrab)
            //get label
            multi.label = extractMultiLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiArray, j))
            //get id
            multi.id = String(Int(ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex(multiArray, j)))

            parseObject[parseContactIdFieldName] = contact
            parseObject[labelFieldName] = multi.label
            parseObject[valueFieldName] = multi.value
            parseObject[multiIdFieldName] = multi.id
            parseObject[typeFieldName] = multi.type
            println("\(multi.type) multi about to be saved with value of \(multi.value)")
            parseObjects.insert(parseObject, atIndex: j)
        }//if
    }//for
    PFObject.saveAll(parseObjects)
}//updateMultiField
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems trying to save the same parseObject 2 times without retrieving it in between. the last save will be always ignored since the object you are trying to save is outdated (a newest version is already on server).

you should retrieve the parseObject from server and then change and save again.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I think you're saying I should add a fetch() or fetchAll(), which then waits for the save and grabs the results - is that right?  I added a PFObject.fetchAll() but the app is now hanging after the first record is saved:         PFObject.saveAll(parseObjects)
        PFObject.fetchAll(parseObjects)

Comment: I misunderstood - you were saying "create a new object every time", which worked!  I'll update my question with the fixed code. Thanks again!

Comment: glad to help, Yes you should create a new object.